# printing from chrome missing lines

Tags: google-chrome, printing-web-page

When I print from `Chrome` some lines are missing.
When I export to a `PDF` file and then print the file from `Acrobat` there are no missing lines.

With `Chrome` for any given web page it is always the same lines that are missing.
No problem printing with `Explorer` or `Firefox`.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have any more details? Is your problem similar to this: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/si_JgCRApPA%5B1-25-false%5D

Comment: Hi josh, Yes that describes the situation almost exactly. I have tried some of the suggestions. Although I like chrome I don't use it anymore Firefox and ie are fine. Btw other computers at my house are fine with chrome.

Comment: >1 yr later, I'm still getting this issue... no one have a fix/root cause, yet?

Comment: Adding my frustration on this as well. Randomly missing part of the page (in this case an invoice), and just leaves it blank (not part lines, but the whole word missing). Never used to do this :/

Answer (score 0):

Check margin settings in the print dialog of Chrome. Setting "Margins" to "None" might help but printer will still have some unavoidable margins. It seems to be a bug in Chrome anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Lines ending in the footer region apparently get lost when the header&footer are not printed. My workaround is to print the header&footer.